# Why is Vim ignoring my `expandtab` setting?

Tags: vimrc, options, tab-characters

In my vimrc, I have `set expandtab`. When I edit a Tex file, however, Vim inserts tab characters , instead of spaces , when I press tab. I figured `noexpandtab` must be set by the TeX ftplugin for some strange reason, but I was wrong. If I type `set expandtab?` , it returns `noexpandtab`. Also, `verbose set expandtab?` reveals that Vim believes my vimrc has instead set `noexpandtab`.

Executing `verbose set expandtab?` returns `noexpandtab Last set from ~/.config/vim/vimrc line 69`.
Line 69 of my vimrc is `set expandtab`

Is this a bug? I can set `expandtab` in my Vim session with a TeX file open and new tabs are spaces as expected. Am I missing something?

Comment: https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-25.3

Comment: What is the exact output of `set verbose et?` in particular what is the line nb mentioned and what is the content of the `.vimrc` in particular at the mentioned line nb (maybe you have `expandtab` mentioned twice or indirectly)

Comment: `verbose set expandtab?` returns `noexpandtab Last set from ~/.config/vim/vimrc line 69`. Line 69 of my vimrc is `set expandtab`.

Comment: Do you run the command `set verbose et?` when the `TeX` buffer is loaded or right after Vim has started? To analyze your TeX problem you have to run the command when the focus is on the TeX buffer.

Comment: Some times , the userid may be the culprit Eg , you may be running vim as root , but you may be checking "~/.config/vim/vimrc" in your home Directory. I would double check whether line 69 is "set expandtab" or "set noexpandtab" in the Correct vimrc. I would add some newlines to the vimrc to move that setting to line 75 & then recheck what vim reports !

Comment: `~/.config/vim/vimrc` looks funky.

Comment: Hm, try `setlocal` instead of `set` in your queries. Also the path ~/.config/vim/vimrc is unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had `set binary` in my vimrc from years ago. Removing this option fixed the problem. The Vim documentation says that `binary` will set `expandtab` (among other settings) to off. However, this is not reported by `set expandtab?` or `verbose set expandtab?`.

On a side not, my vimrc is in non-traditional location. I export `VIMINIT=source ~/.config/vim/vimrc`. The same behavior as described in my question and this answer occurs even if the vimrc is placed in `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 2):

As [you figured out](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/42865/343), the problem was that the option was set as a result of setting another option. I opened [an issue about this](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/12837), and the Vim developers sprang into action and fixed it a few days later.

[As of Vim 9.0.1781](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/757593c07a4f4ac43eb6c6e52fc299abc9bc08bc), the verbose command should correctly report where option have been set indirectly.

(I'll update this with the actual output as soon as I've had a chance to test it.)